# How to fetch data from records as column names

Tags: sql

here is an example how my SQL table data looks like:

```
ts              name    avg
1/1/2019 12:01  tag1    10
1/1/2019 12:01  tag2    15
1/1/2019 12:02  tag1    11
1/1/2019 12:02  tag2    16
```

and here is how i wish to fetch results:

```
ts             tag1 tag2
1/1/2019 12:01  10  15
1/1/2019 12:02  11  16
```

Volume of Data is big:
There are 600+ unique tags and months of minute-wise days

Not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregation`

```
select ts,
       sum(case when name='tag1' then avg end) as tag1,
       sum(case when name='tag2' then avg end) as tag2
  from tab
 group by ts
```

Comment: Thanks. Just added information about data size. Will the recommended solution change?

Comment: you're welcome @luvlogic size not matters. But need to write explicitly for each tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pivot it I think

```
select * from 
(
    select ts,name, AVG(avg) as averagePoint from tableName group by ts,name
)   groupedResult
PIVOT 
(
    AVG(averagePoint) for name IN ([Tag1],[Tag2])
)pivotResult
```